# How to get the correct angle of the ellipse after approximation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, discrete-mathematics, conic-sections, quadratics

I need to get the correct angle of rotation of the ellipses. These ellipses are examples. I have a canonical coefficients of the equation of the five points.

$$Ax ^ 2 + Bxy + Cy ^ 2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0$$

Ellipses:

[image]

Points:

```
Zero ellipse:   [16,46]  [44,19]  [50,35]  [31,61]  [17,54]
First ellipse:  [14,95]  [47,71]  [55,83]  [23,107] [16,103]
Second ellipse: [12,128] [36,117] [58,128] [35,146] [13,136]
Third ellipse:  [16,164] [29,157] [54,188] [40,195] [17,172]
Fourth ellipse: [22,236] [31,207] [50,240] [40,252] [26,244]
```

Coefficients:

```
Zero ellipse                 First ellipse                Second ellipse                Third ellipse                  Fourth ellipse
A: 0.00039679682899033947    A: 0.00007365946131786486    A: 0.000021675708916102692    A: 0.00004189611868790682      A: 0.00004418821462144713
B: 0.00021821614636627075    B: 0.00006770936206052314    B: -0.000002834437159146921   B: -0.00004283926773569747     B: -0.000012890924982902275
C: 0.00024184103978866782    C: 0.00009244517004290531    C: 0.000057745675577137415    C: 0.00003944519997403195      C: 0.000020104667194164587
D: -0.03490717401354479      D: -0.01110309000831378      D: -0.0011544916677563865     D: 0.0046141642800698515       D: -0.00016090203479326006
E: -0.026421911476591453     E: -0.01877226426820658      E: -0.015086084806642279      E: -0.012396706675782408       E: -0.008774013189179199
F: 1.0                       F: 1.0                       F: 1.0                        F: 1.0                         F: 1.0
```

I successfully find the coordinates of the center and the length of the axes. But I get the wrong rotation.

I get the angle using the equation:
$$\theta = \frac{1}{2} \arctan \left( \frac{B}{A-C} \right) $$

Angles result:

```
Zero ellipse:    0.4766612094205555
First ellipse:  -0.6500786401646479
Second ellipse:  0.03921024408607312
Third ellipse:  -0.7568233305427435
Fourth ellipse: -0.24572750447422026
```

Visualization of the result:

[image]

How do I calculate the correct angle? And how to convert the value to degrees without errors?

## UPDATED:

I wrote the algorithm [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mcpu8qac/3). The first set points angle is not correct. In the second set of points, the correct angle. You can put your own values and see the result.

## UPDATED: SOLVED!

Based on the response of @Ng Chung Tak, I managed to get into the code and implement the right formula!

Implementation of the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mcpu8qac/4/).

Formula:

> $$\theta = \tan^{-1}
>  \left(
>    \frac{C-A}{B}+\frac{\sqrt{(A-C)^{2}+B^{2}}}{B} \:
>  \right) $$

Result:

[image]

Thanks to all!

Comment: Wouldn't it be $\theta =  \arctan \left( \frac{B}{A-C} \right)$  without the $\frac{1}{2}$ due to the fact that the coefficient of $xy$ is $B$ instead $2B$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, this equation gave me here http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1824974

Comment: @JeanMarie, without $1/2$ I get the following result: https://swinechat.com/other/image_3.jpg

Comment: I was wrong. Sorry for that. But now I see another reason: I think that you are not doing the rotation around the center of the ellipse but around the origin of the axes.

Comment: @JeanMarie, I make rotation about the red point (center)

Comment: But do you have the following three steps : - one for driving the ellipse center onto the origin - one for making the rotation - one for sending back the origin onto the center of the ellipse ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, For visualization of ellipses, I use the standard method of canvas. I do calculations on the link above. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/ellipse

Do you have any idea how to write an equation?

Comment: In case it helps: Multiply by $180/\pi \approx 57.295779513$ to convert radians to degrees. (Your arctangents appear to be in radians, which is expected if you're using standard math libraries.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang, thank you, but it does not solve the problem. https://swinechat.com/other/image_4.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There're two principal axes in general, so

\begin{align*}
  \theta &=\frac{1}{2} \tan^{-1} \frac{B}{A-C}+\frac{n\pi}{2} \\
  &= \tan^{-1}
     \left(
       \frac{C-A}{B} \color{red}{\pm} \frac{\sqrt{(A-C)^{2}+B^{2}}}{B} \:
     \right) \\
\end{align*}

The centre is given by $$(h,k)=
\left(
  \frac{2CD-BE}{B^2-4AC}, \frac{2AE-BD}{B^2-4AC}
\right)$$

Transforming to
$$\frac{A+C \color{red}{\pm} \sqrt{(A-C)^{2}+B^{2}}}{2} x'^2+
\frac{A+C \color{red}{\mp} \sqrt{(A-C)^{2}+B^{2}}}{2} y'^2+
\frac
{\det
  \begin{pmatrix}
    A & \frac{B}{2} & \frac{D}{2} \\
    \frac{B}{2} & C & \frac{E}{2} \\
    \frac{D}{2} & \frac{E}{2} & F
  \end{pmatrix}}
{\det
  \begin{pmatrix}
    A & \frac{B}{2} \\
    \frac{B}{2} & C \\
  \end{pmatrix}}=0$$

where $\begin{pmatrix} x' \\ y' \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
   \cos \theta & \sin \theta \\
  -\sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} x-h \\ y-k \end{pmatrix}$.

The axes will match, up to reflection about the axes of symmetry, when the $\color{red}{\text{case}}$ (upper or lower) agrees.

> **Numerical example**

> Given five points: $(2,1)$, $(1,1)$, $(-2,-2)$, $(-1,-2)$, $(1,-1)$

> $A=1$, $B=-2$, $C=2$, $D=-1$, $E=2$, $F=-2$

> $$(h,k)=(0,-0.5)$$

> $$\det
>   \begin{pmatrix}
>     A & \frac{B}{2} & \frac{D}{2} \\
>     \frac{B}{2} & C & \frac{E}{2} \\
>     \frac{D}{2} & \frac{E}{2} & F
>   \end{pmatrix} = ACF-\frac{A E^2+C D^2+F B^2-EDB}{4}=-\frac{5}{2}$$

> $$\det
>   \begin{pmatrix}
>     A & \frac{B}{2} \\
>     \frac{B}{2} & C
>   \end{pmatrix} = -\frac{B^2}{4}+AC=1$$

> $$\frac{A+C \pm \sqrt{(A-C)^{2}+B^{2}}}{2}=\frac{3 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$$

> Using upper case convention:

> $$\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2} x'^2+\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2} y'^2=\frac{5}{2}$$

> $$\frac{x'^2}{a^2}+\frac{y'^2}{b^2}=1$$

> $$(x',y')= (a\cos t,b\sin t)$$

> where $\displaystyle \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix}=
> \begin{pmatrix}
>   \sqrt{\frac{5}{3+\sqrt{5}}} \\
>   \sqrt{\frac{5}{3-\sqrt{5}}}
> \end{pmatrix}$

> $$\theta = \tan^{-1}
>      \left(
>        \frac{C-A}{B}+\frac{\sqrt{(A-C)^{2}+B^{2}}}{B} \:
>      \right) =
>   \tan^{-1} \left( -\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2} \right)
>   \approx -58.28^{\circ} $$

> \begin{align*}
>     \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} &=
>     \begin{pmatrix}
>       \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\
>       \sin \theta &  \cos \theta
>     \end{pmatrix}
>     \begin{pmatrix} x' \\ y' \end{pmatrix}+
>     \begin{pmatrix} h \\ k \end{pmatrix} \\  &&\\
>     &=
>     \begin{pmatrix} 
>       h+x'\cos \theta-y'\sin \theta \\
>       k+x'\sin \theta+y'\cos \theta \end{pmatrix} \\  &&\\
>     &=
>     \begin{pmatrix} 
>       \sqrt{\frac{5}{2}+\sqrt{5}\,} \, \sin t+
>       \sqrt{\frac{5}{2}-\sqrt{5}\,} \, \cos t \\
>       -\frac{1}{2}+
>       \frac{\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5}}}{2} \, \sin t-
>       \frac{\sqrt{5-\sqrt{5}}}{2} \, \cos t \end{pmatrix}
>   \end{align*}

Comment: On the basis of your formula, I received the following values. How can I apply them to produce correct angle? https://swinechat.com/other/image_7.jpg

Comment: Rearrange your transformed ellipse as $\displaystyle \left( \frac{x'}{a} \right)^2+\left( \frac{y'}{b} \right)^2=1$, then $(x',y')=( a\cos t, b\sin t)$, now do the inverse transform $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x' \\ y' \end{pmatrix} +\begin{pmatrix} h \\ k \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Please write in the answer the call sequence of formulas that I can integrate into my code, to get the correct angle of the ellipse

Comment: I only familiar with Mathematica or Geogebra, is it OK for you?

Comment: Yes. I need help to get the formula that I can use to get the right angle. You have written a lot of formulas and I do not understand how to properly and in what order to use them, that would get an angle on the basis of the coefficients after approximation.

Comment: Have you learnt any linear algebra before?

Comment: Yes, but that was long ago

Comment: Thank you! Thanks to your answer I have been able to get the right angle!

Answer (score 2):

Justification of the formula:

After centering (translation to let the linear terms vanish), the equation becomes
$$Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+F'=0.$$

Then you apply a rotation of angle $\theta$ to let the mixed term $Bxy$ vanish from the quadratic terms,

$$A(x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta)^2+B(x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta)(x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta)+C(x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta)^2.$$

This is achieved when

$$2(C-A)\cos\theta\sin\theta+2B(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)=(C-A)\sin(2\theta)+2B\cos(2\theta)=0.$$

(Then you can rewrite $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$.)

Hence,

$$\tan(2\theta)=\frac{2B}{A-C}.$$

The angle $\theta$ is undeterminate by a multiple of a quater turn, as the ellipse has two symmetry axis.

Answer (score 1):

Although it sounds like a question, for calculation did you use atan2 function or atan function? *Quadrant* placement is also important.

Comment: I used atan. I made the same way as written here http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1824974

Comment: The given formula is correct. It is better to first check for  trapping the error if your program runs ok when D=E=0 for the (easier,  no center displacement) central conics,

Comment: This site calculates the correct values for the ellipses on the coefficients. The problem is not coefficients?
The calculation for the first three ellipses:
https://goo.gl/qaQ7UZ
https://goo.gl/hR0kaa
https://goo.gl/5KU0Br

Comment: As you can see, this website makes the correct calculation using my coefficients. So, evidently, not a problem in the coefficients.

https://swinechat.com/other/image_5.jpg

Comment: How to use my coefficients to get the right angle? Just as it makes "wolframalpha".

Comment: Can you check $angles$ with central conics?

Comment: You mean to take into account the point relative to the origin? https://swinechat.com/other/image_6.jpg

Comment: Like for $ a x^2 \pm 2 c\, x\,y + b y^2 =1 , $ the natural choice is origin.

Comment: I wrote the algorithm here. The first set points angle is not correct. In the second set of points, the correct angle. You can put your own values and see the result http://jsfiddle.net/mcpu8qac/3

Comment: @ ja72  Found no coding error so far, can you please check this?