# Area enclosed by the curve $5x^2+6xy+2y^2+7x+6y+6=0$

Tags: geometry

We have to find the area enclosed by the curve
$$5x^2+6xy+2y^2+7x+6y+6=0.$$

I tried and I got that it is an ellipse, and I know its area is $\pi ab$ where $a$ and $b$ are the semiaxis lengths of the ellipse.

But I am unable to find the value of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Have you tried to complete the squares ?

Comment: @Meadara What about the cross term in $xy$?

Comment: @Bacon yes that is the main problem

Comment: @Bacon , sorry my bad ,the ellipse is tilted , try using the transformation x=x'-y' and y=x'+y'

Comment: @Meadara Can we do something by finding its centre then solving

Comment: Where did this problem come from?  Unless there's some trick we're missing, this problem is a mess.

Comment: @tilper then what is the trick

Comment: If I knew that, I'd post it as an answer.  :) $\qquad$

Comment: @tilper can you also tell me by finding its centre also

Comment: @koolman See my answer for another question [HERE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839510/how-to-get-the-correct-angle-of-the-ellipse-after-approximation/1840050#1840050)

Answer (score 4):

I think that the bests approach is to see that the general equation of an ellipse you have written above is the result of a standard ellipse that has suffered a rotation about the axes. Can you find a coordinate transformation such as

\begin{align}
x' &= x \cos \theta - y \sin \theta \\
y' &= x\cos \theta + y \sin \theta
\end{align}
That would render the general equation in the form
$$\frac{(x'-h)^{2}}{a^{2}}+ \frac{(y'-k)^{2}}{b^{2}}=m, \qquad (a, b, h, k, m) \in \mathbb{R}$$
From which you could readily find the area?

Comment: How to find thetha

Comment: +1 for "suffered a rotation about the axes" but the RHS of the transformed equation will not (and should not) be zero, and the (un)rotated ellipse is not necessarily centered at the origin.

Comment: @tilper Quite right, I was ahead of myself, many thanks for the +1 and thanks for the  picking up on my sloppy standard ellipse.

Comment: Why not set $m=1$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Let
$$ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$$
Note
$$\tan 2\theta=\frac{b}{a-c}$$
or
$$\cot \theta=\frac{a-c}{b}+\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{a-c}{b}\right)^2}$$
we have
$$\cot \theta=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$$
find $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ and apply
\begin{cases}
x=X\cos\theta-Y\sin\theta\\
y=X\sin\theta+Y\cos\theta
\end{cases}

Comment: Can we do something by finding its centre then solving

Comment: By this changing, $xy$ vanishes and we will have a standard equation.

Comment: Indeed, we have $AX^2+BX^2+CX+DY+E=0$ where $E=f$

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki, $BY^2$.

Comment: Yes . It was typo. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The center:

find the minimum of $(5x^2 + 6xy + 2y^2 + 7x + 2y)$
$\frac {\partial}{\partial x}(5x^2 + 6xy + 2y^2 + 7x + 2y) = 10x + 6y + 7= 0\\
\frac {\partial}{\partial y}(5x^2 + 6y + 2y^2 + 7x + 2y) = 6x + 4y + 6= 0$

Solve this system of equations
$x = 2, y = -4.5$

$2(x-2)^2 + 6(x-2)(y+4.5)+5(y+4.5)^2 = 0.5$
$4(x-2)^2 + 12(x-2)(y+4.5)+10(y+4.5)^2 = 1$

$\mathbf x^T\begin{bmatrix}
4&6\\
6&10\end{bmatrix}\mathbf x =1$

Now we can find the eigenvalues of that matrix, but rather than solving for them I am just going to call them $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$

$x'^2 \lambda_1 + y'^2 \lambda_2 = 1$

$\lambda_1\lambda_2 = \frac 1{(ab)^2}$
and $\lambda_1\lambda_2$ = determinant of the matrix above = $4$.
$ab = \frac 12$

$A = \frac \pi2$

The transformed equation:

$x'^2 \lambda_1 + y'^2 \lambda_2 = 1$

$\lambda_1 = 7 + \sqrt{45}, \lambda_2 = 7 - \sqrt{45}\\
x' = (x-2) (\cos \theta) + (y+4.5)(\sin \theta)\\
y' = (x-2)(\sin \theta) - (y+4.5)(\cos \theta)\\
\theta = \frac 12 \tan^{-1} 2$

Comment: How that you have equated to 1 , is that equation of new ellipse if not then what is the equation

Comment: How that you have equated to 0.5  , is that equation of new ellipse if not then what is the equation

Comment: @koolman: if you substitute x'->x+2 y'->y-9/2 into your eq you get 5x'^2+2y'^2+6x'y'-1/2=0, which means that 5(x-2)^2+2(y+9/2)^2+6(x-2)(y+9/2)=1/2 (expand and see) is the same ellipse you've got. He only switched the coefficients of x^2 and y^2.

Answer (score 1):

For the curve $ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c = 0$, the center is given by 
\begin{align*}
ax+hy+g &= 0\\
hx+by+f &= 0
\end{align*}
and the equation of the ellipse with the axes through the center parallel to the axes is 
\begin{align*}
ax^2+2hxy+by^2 + c' = 0
\end{align*}
where $c' = gx_c + fy_c + c$, where $(x_c, y_c)$ is the center.

Comment: But in that also term xy is coming

Comment: The axes are parallel to the coordinate axes not the axes of the ellipse.

Comment: It can be shown that the area of the ellipse given by $ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$ is $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{ab-h^2}}$.

Comment: @Muralidharan: Only if your $c'=-1$. The scaling to make it $-1$ also scales the area: $A=\frac{\pi}{\text{scaling factor}\sqrt{ab-h^2}}$.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland, Yes, you are correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Doug M solves your problem. I just want to expand on it to the general ellipse.

Assume $$ax^2+2bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$$ is an ellipse ($ac-b^2>0, a>0$). It has center $x=\frac{eb-cd}{2(ac-b^2)}, y=\frac{bd-ae}{2(ac-b^2)}$, which means that when the equation transforms to $$ax'^2+2bx'y'+cy'^2+f-\frac{ae^2-2bde+cd^2}{4(ac-b^2)}=0,$$ that is $f-\frac{ae^2-2bde+cd^2}{4(ac-b^2)}$ is negative (if not the conic is just a point or doesn't have real points). We need to multiply this by the $g>0$ so that $g(f-\frac{ae^2-2bde+cd^2}{4(ac-b^2)})=-1$. Then $agx'^2+2bgx'y'+cgy'^2-1=0$ and the area is $\frac{\pi}{g\sqrt{ac-b^2}}$ by Doug M's method.

For your equation $g=2$ and $ac-b^2=1$ so $A=\frac{\pi}{2}$.