# Finding the equation of an ellipse using eccentricity and directrix with focus at (0,0)

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

The ellipse $\varepsilon$ has eccentricty $\frac{1}{2}$, focus $(0,0)$ and the line $x=-1$ as the corresponding directrix. Find the equation of $\varepsilon$. Find the other focus and directrix of $\varepsilon$.

I'm confused by this due to fact the focus is at $(0,0)$. As far as I was aware the center of the ellipse should be at $(0,0)$ so that the foci are at $(c,0)$ and $(-c,0)$, where $c^2=a^2-b^2$. The directrix corresponding to the focus will then be given by the equation $x=\frac{a^2}{c}$, and the eccentricity of the ellipse is $\frac{c}{a}$. Is there another set of equations I can use to determine the equation of the ellipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your information:

\begin{align*}
  \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{x+1} &= \varepsilon \\
  x^2+y^2 &= \varepsilon^2(x+1)^2 \\
  (1-\varepsilon^2)x^2-2\varepsilon^2 x+y^2 &= \varepsilon^2 \\
  \left[
    (1-\varepsilon^2)x^2-2\varepsilon^2 x+
    \frac{\varepsilon^4}{1-\varepsilon^2}
  \right]+
  y^2 &= \varepsilon^2+\frac{\varepsilon^4}{1-\varepsilon^2} \\
  \frac{(1-\varepsilon^2)^2}{\varepsilon^2}
  \left(
    x-\frac{\varepsilon^2}{1-\varepsilon^2}
  \right)^2+\frac{1-\varepsilon^2}{\varepsilon^2} y^2 &= 1 \\
  a &= \frac{\varepsilon}{1-\varepsilon^2} \\
  b &= \frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{1-\varepsilon^2}} \\
  c &= \frac{\varepsilon^2}{1-\varepsilon^2} 
\end{align*}

The other focus is
$$(2c,0)=
\left( \frac{2\varepsilon^2}{1-\varepsilon^2},0 \right)$$

The other directrix is
$$x=2c+1$$
$$x=\frac{1+\varepsilon^2}{1-\varepsilon^2}$$

[image]

Comment: I thought ellipses had equations of the form $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$?

Comment: No, it's focus origin.  In polar coordinates it reads $$r(\theta)=\frac{a(1-e^2)}{1-e\cos \theta}=\frac{b^2}{a-c\cos \theta}$$ See more for [**general form**](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839510/how-to-get-the-correct-angle-of-the-ellipse-after-approximation/1840050#1840050)

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm not sure I understand. What is the equation of the ellipse? Is $\varepsilon$ in your equation $\frac{1}{2}$? If I substitute that in will I get the equation of the ellipse?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Okay, I will try that. Thanks.

Comment: Correct some mistakes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48790/discussion-between-serveoverice-and-ng-chung-tak).